# Issue creating the correct CSS Selector

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

I have been at this for a while and am throwing in the towel for help. I am trying to scrap [this page](https://www.uvic.ca/BAN1P/bwckctlg.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=201705&subj_in=BIOL&crse_in=184&schd_in=%25) specifically I am trying to get access to every table row that has information in it as highlighted green in the following picture. I do no need the table headers, just the rows.

[image]

With Scrapy I am able to get to each section area (where it says "Main Campus") with the following selector

```
response.css('.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable')
```

I use **.datadisplaytable** twice because the tables I am trying to select are inside a table with that class. After that what seems logical to me to get to the table row I am after would be to use the following selector

```
response.css('.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable tbody:nth-child(2)')
```

However, I get nothing with this selector. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is a bit off. You're not trying to get the 2nd `<tbody/>` tag.

```
.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable tbody tr:nth-child(n+2)
```

That will get you all the rows, and skip the header for each table.

Comment: I tried that in the scrapy shell  and got nothing back.

Comment: `tr:nth-child(n+2)` selects all tr children that are the 2nd element or later among their siblings.

Comment: @ehThind I'm not familiar with Scrapy, I only verified this by going to my console on that page and checking the result of `$('.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable tbody tr:nth-child(n+2)')`.

Comment: `.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable tr:nth-child(n+2)` without the `tbody` seems to work however, It still provides the headers as well.

Comment: `.datadisplaytable .datadisplaytable tr:nth-child(3)` Works. Thank you every much!